# Why can't i calculate the Inductive reactance in this way?

Tags: voltage, resistance, reactance

Question:
[image]

\$V_1=40sin(1000t)\$,what is the value of  Inductive reactance?

Solution :

\$Z=\frac{V_1}{I}=\frac{40}{8}=5\$,so \$5=\sqrt{R^2+X^2_L}=\sqrt{4^2+X^2_L}\$,so \$X_L=3\$

But i want to ask that why can't i calculate the Inductive reactance  in this way below?

My thinking:

\$Z=4+jX_L\$, and \$Z=\frac{V_1}{I}=\frac{40}{8}=5\$,so \$5=4+jX_L\$,then \$1=jX_L\$,so \$X_L=\frac{1}{j}\$ ,why will i get the wrong answer with this method? what is the problem of this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that \$Z=4+jX_L\$, and \$Z=\frac{V_1}{I}=\frac{40}{8}=5\$, so \$5=4+jX_L\$. However in \$5=4+jX_L\$ the term \$jX_L\$ is a complex number therefore to solve you must use \$5=\sqrt{4^2+X^2_L}\$,so \$X_L=3\$

Answer (score 2):

Your \$I\$ and \$V\$ are complex, but you're neglecting that. \$|I_{eff}|=8\,\text{A}\$ does NOT imply \$I = 8\,\text{A}\$.